# css html 5 responsive website

Tags: css, html

It has been a few days that I am learning CSS and html. I am trying to build a website and my content container works ( is displayed) exactly how I want it on my 17inch laptop. However when i move it to my desktop in moves to the left and comes down to the bottom.

How do i make an element change in accordance to the resolution of a screen.

```
            /* Entire drop-up menu, show on mouse hover */
            #footer_menu li:hover .one_column_layout, 
            #footer_menu li:hover .two_column_layout, 
            #footer_menu li:hover .three_column_layout
            {

           display: block;
           position: absolute;
           margin: auto;
           bottom: 40px;
           border: 1px solid #111111;
           border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
           background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
           bottom: 90px;
           left: 500px;
           width: 500px;
           padding-left: 50px;
           padding-right: 54px;
           font-size: 12px;
           left: 400px;
           }
```

Comment: You need to look into CSS3 media queries.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things to take account to build a responsive site, but the first is about not fixing width in pixels, but in % and/or use media queries.